# How to use where clause referencing a column when querying a JSON object in another column in SQL

Tags: sql, json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following sales table with a nested JSON object:

| sale_id | sale_date | identities |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 41acdd9c-2e86-4e84-9064-28a98aadf834 | 2017-05-13 | {"SaleIdentifiers": [{"type": "ROM", "Classifier": "CORNXP21RTN"}]} |

To query the Classifier I do the following:

```
select Classifier from               

     (select identities.SaleIdentifiers.Classifier
     FROM sales )
     as Classifiers
```

This gives me the result:

| Classifier |
| --- |
| CORNXP21RTN |

How would I go about using the `sale_date` column in a where clause? For instance this shows me a list of the classifiers in a specific `sale_date`:

```
select Classifier from               
    
         (select identities.SaleIdentifiers.Classifier
         FROM sales )
         as Classifiers
where sale_date = '2017-05-13'
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Your column `sale_date` is a string?

Comment: no its a date I have just updated it to show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for subquery:

```
select identities.SaleIdentifiers.Classifier as Classifier
FROM sales 
where sale_date = '2017-05-13'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what database you are using, but it looks like you just need to include the column in the subquery:

```
select Classifier
from (select sale_date, identities.SaleIdentifiers.Classifier
      from sales
     ) as Classifiers
where sale_date = '13/05/2018'
```

Note:  You should be storing the date using a native date format.  And then using ISO standard date formats for comparison -- '2018-05-13' or '20180513'.

Comment: Hey, the database is spark-sql on azure databricks

Comment: I get the following error when I try: Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`sale_date`' given input columns: [Classifiers.Classifier];